# webdriverprefs.json not found - pyinstaller

Tags: python, json, selenium, pyinstaller

I have a python program which uses selenium package, and when creating an exe from this using `pyinstaller` it creates the exe correctly. When trying to open firefox from this app I got the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:\\users\\mohamed\\Temp\\_MEI622\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'
```

I found this solution, but it doesn't work for me:

[Py2exe isn't copying webdriver_prefs.json into builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985627/py2exe-isnt-copying-webdriver-prefs-json-into-builds)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for same, 
when freezing scripts to exe don't use --onefile , use --onedir instead , it will generate one folder for all files and then copy selenium folder in path c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium to your app folder and it works correctly

Answer (score 3):

simply include these (.json & .xpi) files as arbitrary files in your .spec file.

here's what worked for me (you might need to change the paths):

```
needed_selenium_files = [(r'selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver_prefs.json',
                           r'C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver_prefs.json',
                          'DATA'),
                         (r'selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.xpi',        
                           r'C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.xpi',
                           'DATA')]
```

and later on:

```
coll = COLLECT(exe, a.binaries, needed_selenium_files, ...)
```

read more on PyInstaller Manual:
http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#toc-class-table-of-contents
and
http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#adding-files-to-the-bundle

Comment: this worked for me then you should run pyinstaller filename.spec

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) always messes something up when creating executables. I suggest that you use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) instead.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and is primarily opinion based. If someone was coming here looking for how to fix this in PyInstaller, this probably wouldn't help them very much.