# Tkinter, Selenium and py2exe.

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I'm having trouble packaging selenium with py2exe. I have tried a few other "work arounds" on Stack but nothing is working for me. I'm using Python 3.4.3, I'm able to build the tkinter program with py2exe, it launches without a problem and all other functions are working except the selenium part. I get the following error when i try and call the function in the program. 


I have tried to move the .json files. webdriver.xpi seems to work but i always get an error on webdriver_prefs.json file. When i try to move the file "webdriver_prefs.json" into the library.zip i get a corruption error im not sure if that windows is the issue or the file. When i run the program in IDLE it works fine with no errors. 


WHEN PACKAGED IN THE EXE

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "SearchTool.pyw", line 121, in graniteWebSearch
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-    py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 47, in __init__
        self.profile = FirefoxProfile()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-    py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 63, in __init__
        WEBDRIVER_PREFERENCES)) as default_prefs:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:     'H:\\Python\\dist\\SearchTool.exe\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'
```

When Not Packaged in the EXE

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "SearchTool.pyw", line 121, in graniteWebSearch
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-    py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 47, in __init__
        self.profile = FirefoxProfile()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-    py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 63, in __init__
        WEBDRIVER_PREFERENCES)) as default_prefs:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:     'H:\\Python\\dist\\library.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'
```

MY Setup File

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe
    data_files = [("selenium/webdriver/firefox", ["webdriver_prefs.json",           "webdriver.xpi"])]
    manifest = """
    recursive-include *.json
    """
    setup(
        name = 'SearchTool',
        version = 1,
        py_modules = ['selenium', 'tkinter'],
        windows = ["SearchTool.pyw"],
        author = 'That guy',
        author_email = 'someemail',
        url = 'NONE',
        description = 'Basic do all program.',
        data_files=data_files,
        zipfile=None,
        options={
            'py2exe':
                {
                    'skip_archive': False,
                    'bundle_files': 3,
                }
        }
    )
```

Comment: You could try this answer (requires pyinstaller though): [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25709423/3853296](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25709423/3853296)

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot. I got it working with IE for now. One thing I did notice is that Firefox and chrome don't release on alert boxes. When you do a browser.get("url") it hangs if that website has an alert pop up like say when you login to a router. iE releases the prompt so you can tell it to switch to the alert window to enter username and password.

Comment: For now I'm going to stick with IE.