# Getting py2exe to Include (Selenium) .json Files in .zip

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver, py2exe

I have spent all day trying to solve py2exe not including my required Selenium files (webdriver.xpi and webdriver_pref.json) in my .exe's library.zip or inside the .exe which seems to be encountered by many people before.

I have researched many similar questions and have tried to adapt provided answers to no avail (such as [here](http://crazedmonkey.com/blog/python/pkg_resources-with-py2exe.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702621/webdriverprefs-json-not-found-pyinstaller/25709423#25709423)). I have also learnt that manually transferring the files after running py2exe will not work as suggest by some.

My current setup.py looks like this (although I have had many variants that look similar, none of which worked)

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

wd_base = 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver'
RequiredDataFiles = [
    ('selenium/webdriver/firefox', ['%s\\firefox\\webdriver.xpi'%(wd_base), '%s\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'%(wd_base)])
]

setup(
    console=['test.py'],
    data_files=RequiredDataFiles,
    options={
            "py2exe":{
                "skip_archive": True,
                "unbuffered": True,
                "optimize": 2
            }
        }
)
```

and I always get the error (either in library.zip or test.exe depending on bundle options..)

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 177, in SellClick
  File "test.py", line 383, in seller
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 47, in __init__
    self.profile = FirefoxProfile()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile
.py", line 63, in __init__
    WEBDRIVER_PREFERENCES)) as default_prefs:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\James\\OneDrive\\Python\\dist\\library.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'
```

Has anyone found an easy solution / workaround to tricking py2exe including the .xpi and .json files in the .zip or .exe? If so how would I implement the needed changes?

Thanks,
J

Comment: What about unzipping the `library.zip`?