# Trying to use Py2exe, keep getting errors

Tags: python, py2exe

I have small program made in python with selenium, and now I'm trying to make an .exe with py2exe.. I get the exe but when I run it, terminal just pops up for split second then it terminates.

I tried to run .exe in cmd and It says that there is no such file as `webdriver_prefs.json`

Here is the setup.py I have:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['file_name.py'])
```

Any input on how to resolve this is welcome.

Cheers.

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985627/py2exe-isnt-copying-webdriver-prefs-json-into-builds

Comment: Still same error, even after doing copying both those files :(